# How to modify rails_admin edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, action, rails-admin

I have a `Contact` class associated with `User` class as follows

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :users
end
```

In my edit I want to show a dropdown with list of user name as options that component should bind with `contact.user_id`.

How to achieve this?

Comment: `belongs_to :users` is not correct, it should be `belongs_to :user` - singular.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to achieve this, here is one example.

```
<%= f.select :user_id, Contact.all.collect{|c| [c.user.name, c.user.id]} %>
```

This creates an array of contact.user.name and contact.user.id and submits the selected contact based on the associated user_id to your controller.

You will find more information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease).

Comment: this is a common way. I want to do this inside rails_admin