# How to override rails_admin edit fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I want to include dropdown for the associated columns in rails_admin edit pages.

For example I want to select the user from the dropdown in contact edit.

In my config/initializers/rails_admin.rb

```
config.model 'Contact' do
  edit do
    field :user do
      partial 'edit_user'
    end
  end
end
```

I also have the partial in app/views/rails_admin/main/_edit_user.html.haml

but I didn't get the expected view. How to do this?

Comment: You have asked this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103224/how-to-modify-rails-admin-edit-view/14103347#14103347 perhaps consider offering a bounty?

Answer (score 2):

I think (correct me if i'm wrong) that you want the field to be shown as a dropdown list of the users in your database. Have you read this page: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Enumeration ?

You can create a enum method for the field in your model and in the initializer
call it like this:

```
field :user, :enum do
   enum_mehod do :user_enum end
end
```

Comment: This is such an incredibly powerful feature... love RailsAdmin!